# Privilege pages show accept rate in screenshots

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page

On the following two pages, the screenshots show a usercard with the `##% accept rate` still listed. Since the accept rate feature has been removed, the screenshots are now inaccurate:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user
2. https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads

Comment: @NullCatPonyPuppyPointer I agree with you, but it was decided [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) to remove its visibility.

Comment: This has not yet been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66259/12) and [done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66254/7). After the cache updates (could take a while), there will be no trace<sup>1</sup> of accept rate on all privilege pages. It has been completely wiped out from existence by my PRISM-approved whiteout.

This meeting never happened.

*Self destructs*

<sup>1. Except, well, in the revision history</sup>